# LOAD DATA INFILE from server does not work

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I'm using this syntax to insert 50 records into a mySQL table from within a php script:

```
$sql    = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/myusername/timeshts/hmo/tiertwo/myBuilders/BuilderTwo/sql-cron-files/overtime-item.sql' INTO TABLE `ot-item` CHARACTER SET 'utf8' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
if($result) { echo "Load data Done!!!"; }
```

I'm mainly used to Windows paths and locations, this is Linux and i think its a path issue - i'm using an absolute server path since im not sure where the 'data directory or database directory is as advised in the mySQL documentation. I suppose i haven't got access to either of these directories on a shared host - so absolute is my best bet. Is there something i'm missing in the syntax that i just cant see?? I wrote the script so i know that lines are terminated by a new line character and columns are separated with a single commma char.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but maybe you are missing a / at the beginning of the path.

Comment: hi, i actually used a fwd-slash at the beginning and then tried without it - i'll edit my question and add it again just for clarity - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need file privilege .

Contact your DBA to execute below command

grant file on *.* to 'usr'@'%';

Comment: i'll give that a go and get back with an update to help anyone else with this frustrating issue.

Comment: So Nothing more. check file permission for ls -lrth /home/myusername/timeshts/hmo/tiertwo/myBuilders/BuilderTwo/sql-cron-files/overtime-item.sql weather mysql process having permissions or not.

Comment: still waiting to get reply from DBA on hosting - ive looked at the file permissions and, overtime-item.sql script has 644 - parent and subfolders that it resides in all have, 755 - didnt really understand your last reply (im a Win user remember :-)